# Is it possible to redirect debug logs in ObjectBox?

Tags: android, objectbox

I have a user who I've diagnosed to have object-box-related issues.  I can send him debug builds with the ObjectBox debug flags (`debugFlags()`, `debugRelations()`, etc...) turned on.  However, I would like to redirect the object box logs to a callback where I can collect the data and save to a file.   Is this possible in ObjectBox?

Answer (score 1):

Logs are currently created from native (C++) code, so there is no way to redirect them. But I agree a custom logger is a good idea (e.g. to log to an error report file on production builds).

If you have time, please create a feature issue for it at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues.